# Having Statement and Where Statement producing inconsistent results regarding Pokemon data

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause, having

this is my first question. Go easy please!

I am doing an [SQL project in KhanAcademy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql/more-advanced-sql-queries/pp/project-data-dig).  My source data are lines 1-181 of this [pokemon database](https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/26b9357c6120d3d0d27c2b90c950e8c6) (that is, all gen 1 pokemon), and I am running some queries regarding the attack stats of the pokemon.

Running `SELECT Type_1, COUNT(*) FROM pokemon WHERE "Attack" > 120 GROUP BY Type_1;`, I get 15 Total Pokemon grouped by 9 different types, which is what I expect.

However, when I attempt a HAVING statement to find the number of types of Pokemon with at least one pokemon with over 120 Attack, it returns only 4 types.

This is the code: `SELECT Type_1 AS "type" FROM pokemon GROUP BY type_1 HAVING "Attack" > 120;`.

To show an example, one pokemon that is missing from my 2nd query is Machamp: `INSERT INTO pokemon(Number,Name,Type_1,Type_2,Total,HP,Attack,Defense,Sp_Atk,Sp_Def,Speed,Generation,Legendary) VALUES (68,'Machamp','Fighting',NULL,505,90,130,80,65,85,55,1,'False');`

I'm not sure what is wrong from my 2nd query.  Please help if you can.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT Type_1 AS "type"
FROM pokemon
GROUP BY type_1
HAVING "Attack" > 120;
```

is not valid SQL and should be returning an error.  Why?  Because the `HAVING` takes place *after* the `GROUP BY`.  And `Attack` is not defined.  It would need to be in an activation function such as:

```
HAVING MAX(Attack) > 120
```

This version of the query is logically equivalent to:

```
SELECT p.type
FROM (SELECT Type_1 AS "type", MAX(Attack) as max_attack
      FROM pokemon
      GROUP BY type_1
     ) p
WHERE max_Attack > 120
```

Comment: Replacing `HAVING "Attack" > 120;` with `HAVING MAX(Attack) > 120` worked! However, I don't understand your points, as my HAVING is also after my group by, and I'm not sure what you mean about defining attack.  In any case, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> I attempt a `HAVING` statement to find the number of types of Pokemon with at least one pokemon with over 120 Attack

If you want to count how many types of pokemon have at least one pokemon that has more than 120 attacks, then you could add another level of aggregation on top of your existing query, like:

```
select count(*) no_types
from (select 1 from pokemon where attack > 120 group by type_1) t
```

Note that the subquery uses `select 1`: we don't actually need it to return some specific column, all we want to know is how many rows it contains - hence `select 1`, which makes the intent explicit.

Or, we could use `count(distinct)`, which avoids the need for a subquery:

```
select count(distinct type_1) no_types from pokemon where attack > 120
```